# How to pass a string along with an injected dependency in ASP.NET Core v2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have the below method in my Startup.cs class of my ASP.NET Core v2 project. My question is how to setup a class/service where a string value is passed to a class, along with an injected dependency.

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add custom services.
        services.AddSingleton<IMyAssistantClass, MyAssistantClass);
        services.AddSingleton<MyClassManager>(s => new  MyClassManager("connectionString", /* How to inject IMyAssistantClass? */);

        // Other setup....
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddSingleton<IMyAssistantClass, MyAssistantClass);
  services.AddSingleton<MyClassManager>(s => 
    {
      var imy = (IMyAssistantClass) s.GetService(typeof(IMyAssistantClass))
      new  MyClassManager("connectionString", imy);
    }
  );
}
```

// nice way to make it more convenient is to add extension method to `IServiceCollection`, like

```
public static T Resolve<T>(this IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    return (T) serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(T));
}
```

and then you could just call `s.Resolve<IMyAssistantClass>();`

Comment: I recommend using [`GetRequiredService<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getrequiredservice?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceProviderServiceExtensions_GetRequiredService__1_System_IServiceProvider_) instead for two reasons: 1. It's generic, so no need for casts and `typeof` and 2. It's fail-fast for if the dependency isn't found.

Comment: There's already generic extension methods for this on `IServiceProvider`. @KirkLarkin pointed out `GetRequiredService<T>()` which will throw an exception if it doesn't resolve.  There is also `GetService<T>()` which returns null if it doesn't resolve.  These extension methods are in the namespace `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`.

Answer (score 5):

Promote the `connectionString` variable to a Parameter Object and register this object in the container:

```
public class MyClassManagerSettings
{
    public readonly string ConnectionString;

    public MyClassManagerSettings(string connectionString) {
        this.ConnectionString = connectionString
            ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionString));
    }
}

public class MyClassManager
{
    public MyClassManager(
        MyClassManagerSettings settings, IMyAssistantClass assistant)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can register it as follows:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyAssistantClass, MyAssistantClass);
services.AddSingleton<MyClassManager>();
services.AddSingleton(new MyClassManagerSettings("myConnectionString"));
```

Comment: This is definitely the preferred way to do. In my eyes you should avoid adding parameters to classes that are dependency injected. To add to this answer I would recommend using IConfiguration and then have your startup load (GetSection) the connectionstring from appsettings. Then you can inject the Configuration for the connectionstring into your ServiceCollection.